# Any good introductory book/tutorial on Fourier Transform (up to FFT) with plenty of exercises and solutions?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, self-learning, fourier-series, signal-processing

I wonder what could be a good book to start learning in depth all aspects of the Fourier transform up to the FFT algorithm, and beyond.

I am going to dedicate quite some time on the subject, so I expect something with a lot of exercises (calculus, demonstrations) and solutions, from the basics up to the most complex topics.

Could be nice to also have some exercises (with solutions) with practical applications in *Matlab* or *Python/Numpy*.

Any pointers? Tutorials, books, chapters, websites?

thanks! :)

Comment: In case you're not already aware, FFTs are how we do the calculations needed to prove the largest known prime numbers today. http://www.mersenne.org/various/math.php That's one interesting practical (for some definition of "practical") application.

Comment: it depends on your level, and what you really need, and how much time do you have.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it is the best place to start for you -- after all, these things can depend on background and "mathematical maturity" -- but if you are going to be studying Fourier analysis in depth, then it would be a great pity to miss out on Thomas Körner's beautifully written and insightful *Fourier Analysis* (CUP, 1988).

"Ah, but there are no exercises ...."

Oh yes there are, but you have to look along the shelves to find Körner's accompanying book *Exercises in Fourier Analysis* (CUP, 1993) which gives chapter-by-chapter exercises for the original book, over three hundred pages of them!

Comment: book by Körner definitely is a gem, but arguably not the book "to start learning..."

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in "pure mathematical theory" of Fourier analysis, start with the advice by @PeterSmith. If you are looking for a somewhat more applied point of view, here is a nice source:

[A First Course in Fourier Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521709792)

It can be supplemented with the Stanford course of Fourier Analysis:

[web page of the course](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/EE261/137)

with video lectures, nice lecture notes and assignments.

Comment: Is the First Course in Fourier Analysis by Kammler? The link is no longer valid. Also the link to the Stanford course is broken now too.

Comment: @William Yes, Kammler, but the link works fine for me.  I will fix the second link.

Comment: @Artem : the answer depends on his level, and what he really needs, and how much time does he have.

Comment: For some reason the rads.stackexchange.com links never work for me, I don't know why.

Comment: and a link to amazon is just ridiculus... come on my friend ! we are on internet, the place where everything is downloadable for free !

Answer (score 1):

*The Fourier Transform And Its Applications* by Ronald N. Bracewell.